# How can I merge rows (of a particular column) having the same value in  SQL Server Reports RDL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, bids, rdl

I'm new to working with SQL Server 2005 Reporting Servives using RDLs in BIDS.

I need to modify an existing report so that I can merge cells in adjacent rows which would have the same value for that particular column.

Ex: consider this is the table returned from the stored procedure used by the reports RDL.

```
_________________________________________________  
Id      SubCategory    Field1     Field2   Total  
_________________________________________________  
1       a              Bob        US       17  
1       b              John       UK       17  
2       a              Mary       AUS      12  
3       d              Ram        IND      19  
4       b              Alex       UK       09  
4       c              Abby       FR       09  
5       e              Tim        IT       03  
_________________________________________________
```

Table Example - Couldn' Format Text :( Image here : http_://i.stack.imgur.com/gWEH5.png_

What I need to do is I want the cells merged into one where two adjacent rows in the same column have the same value.

Like `Id 1` is repeated twice, so the cells for these must be merged. (Also `4`)

Similarly for the last column `Total` for cells with Ids `1` and `4` must be merged.

The RDL has "TextBox" for columns, I saw some other questions in this forum but were related to `Tablix` or Matrix, so I thought it would be better if I mentioned it.

I need this merging to be done in the RDL, and this should also be present when exported to Excel.

Hoping someone will be able to help soon.

Comment: What happens to subcat, field1 and field2?

Comment: Thanks for you response Sam.

Those fields would remain in their independent (separate) rows itself;
I forgot to mention that the merged cells would occupy the space of the no of rows that were merged. (similar to merging in Excel Sheets)

Comment: How you achieved this ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the SQL query to use a group by on ID.

Answer (score 0):

in reporting services drag Id On Row group Of Tablix Upaer than Detail Group
and drag other Fields(except Total) Besid ID  and befor vertical dash line In the table.
and drag Total to first cell afte vertical dash line